# parallax navigation menu title to show

Tags: css, html, parallax

Hi I am trying to create a single webpage website. I was able to create the navigation on the right side using circle, but it does not show the title(which is the name of each part of the menu.)

This webpage is example of the menu on the right side. http://jonathannicol.com/projects/parallax-scrolling/

Here is my CSS & HTML code:

```css
#fp-nav {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 52;
 top: 50%;
 right: 15px;
 padding: 0 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -ms-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -o-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 transform: translatez(0);
 -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#fp-nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#fp-nav ul li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.color-weight-light #fp-nav ul li.active a {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: solid 2px #000;
}

.color-weight-light #fp-nav ul li a {
 background color: #000;
}

#fp-nav ul li.active a {
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 margin-left: -1px;
}

#fp-nav ul li a {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -moz-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -ms-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -o-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
  background color: #000;
}

.color-weight-light#fp-nav ul li .nav-title {
 color: #000;
}

.nav-title {
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-family: "brandon-grotesque";
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: normal;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-top: -11px;
 padding: 0 0 5px 0;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-beizer(.23,1,.32,1);
 -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-beizer(.23,1,.32,1);
 -ms-transition: all .3s cubic-beizer(.23,1,.32,1);
 -o-transition: all .3s cubic-beizer(.23,1,.32,1);
 transition: all .3s cubic-beizer(.23,1,.32,1);
 line-height: 32px;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5a33902e83.js"></script>
<div id="fp-nav" style="margin-top: -46px;" class="color-weight-light">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#top">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Home</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#content">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Slim Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-one">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Blogs</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-two">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Heatlh Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-three">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Video</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-four">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Skin Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Is there anyway I can fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. CSS edited at the bottom of style.

```css
#fp-nav {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 52;
 top: 50%;
 right: 15px;
 padding: 0 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -ms-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -o-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 transform: translatez(0);
 -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#fp-nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#fp-nav ul li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.color-weight-light #fp-nav ul li.active a {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: solid 2px #000;
}

.color-weight-light #fp-nav ul li a {
 background color: #000;
}

#fp-nav ul li.active a {
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 margin-left: -1px;
}

#fp-nav ul li a {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -moz-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -ms-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -o-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
  background color: #000;
}

.color-weight-light#fp-nav ul li .nav-title {
 color: #000;
}


.nav-title {
opacity: 0;
visibility: visible;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 20px;
text-align: right;
width: 200px;
transition:1s;
}

li:hover .nav-title {
opacity:1;
}

li a{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5a33902e83.js"></script>
<div id="fp-nav" style="margin-top: -46px;" class="color-weight-light">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#top">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Home</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#content">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Slim Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-one">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Blogs</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-two">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Heatlh Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-three">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Video</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-four">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Skin Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it shows me the letter on the left side of the circle, but it does not show me whole letters..

Comment: In the snippet above or your site? What browser are you using?

Comment: In my website! In the snippet, it works well. I'm using Chrome/

Comment: In that case you have more css that overwrites this one. Inspect your `ul`, `li` and `span` and look  for `overflow:hidden` or width:[XX]px. Can you provide link to site?

Comment: I found the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change style to...

```
.nav-title { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
```

Comment: it shows me the title, but it's showing below the circle. Thanks!

Comment: don't remove the style just change the value in opacity and visibility